# HTML tags in XML sitemap when inspecting elements

Tags: html, .net, xml, umbraco, sitemap

My Umbraco 8 XML sitemap is displaying html tags and I don't know why! Content Type header shows it's a text/xml document, but when inspecting elements the page includes html markup. The sitemap is using a cshtml template as directed by Umbraco documentation on creating an XML sitemap, with Layout = "null". What could be the issue here? And is it an issue to begin with? This is for SEO purposes, not for people to be reading, so it needs to be a proper XML sitemap.

[Screenshot of xml view file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnnVK.png)

[Screenshot of sitemap with dev tools network tab open, showing the content type header is text/xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmQf4.png)

[Screenshot of sitemap with dev tools elements tag open, showing the file contains html tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98XTP.png)

Comment: Posting code as images is not recommended, should always be posted as plain text. Please post a sample of the real xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the HTML you are seeing is from the browser tool that's displaying the XML for you. It's not your code.